# Removing lines in one file that are present in another file using python

Tags: python

I am stuck with removing lines that are present a file using the lines present another file in python. I am using two for loops for string matching  but it gives duplicate lines on second itration of loop. Is there any other ways to do it. Thanks

```
with open('results.csv','r+') as source:
    lines = source.readlines()

f = open('results_comments.csv','r')
line = f.readlines()
for l in line:
    for L in lines:
        if L!=l:
            source.write(L)
f.close()
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you edited it to include a worked example.

Comment: From the files' name it looks like you are working with csv files. Am I right?

Comment: no, just for naming. its a plan text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
with open('results.csv','r') as source:
    lines_src = source.readlines()

with open('results_comments.csv','r') as f:
    lines_f = f.readlines()

destination = open("destination.csv","w")
for data in lines_src:
    if data not in lines_f:
        destination.write(data)

destination.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable names are confusing so I've renamed a couple.  I think you'll need to open a new file for writing the results (at least that will make it clearer what you're trying to do). You can rename the file afterwards if you want the same name.

```
with open('results.csv','r+') as source:
    filter_lines = source.readlines()

with open('results_comments.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('target.csv', 'w') as target:
    for line in lines:
        if line not in filter_lines:
            target.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('results.csv','r+') as source:
     lines = source.readlines()

f = open('results_comments.csv','r')
line = f.readlines()
line = filter(lambda x : x not in lines, line)
f.write('\n'.join(line))
f.close()
```