# Rebuild tables from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing an issue where a data supplier is generating a dump of his multi-tenant databases in a single table. Recreating the original tables is not impossible, the problem is I am receiving millions of rows every day. Recreating everything, every day, is out of question.

Until now, I was using SSIS to do so, with a lookup-intensive approach. In the past year, my virtual machine went from having 2 GB of ram to 128, and still growing.

Let me explain the disgrace:

Imagine a database where users have posts, and posts have comments. In my real scenario, I am talking about 7 distinct tables. Analyzing a few rows, I have the following:

```
+-----+------+------+--------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
| Id* | T_Id | U_Id | U_Name | P_Id | P_Content | C_Id |   C_Content    |
+-----+------+------+--------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
|   1 |    1 |    1 | john   |    1 | hello     |    1 | hello answer 1 |
|   2 |    1 |    2 | maria  |    2 | cake      |    2 | cake answer 1  |
|   3 |    2 |    1 | pablo  |    1 | hello     |    1 | hello answer 3 |
|   4 |    2 |    1 | pablo  |    2 | hello     |    2 | hello answer 2 |
|   5 |    1 |    1 | john   |    3 | nosql     |    3 | nosql answer 1 |
+-----+------+------+--------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
```

- the Id is from my table
- T_Id is the "tenant" Id, which identifies multiple databases

I have imagined the following possible solution:

I make a query that selects non-existent Ids for each table, such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.t_id, 
                n.c_id, 
                n.c_content 
FROM   mytable n 
WHERE  n.id > 4 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   mytable o 
                       WHERE  o.id <= 4 
                              AND n.t_id = o.t_id 
                              AND n.c_id = o.c_id)
```

This way, I am able to select only the new occurrences whenever a new Id of a table is found. Although it works, it may perform badly when working with 100s of millions of rows.

Could anyone share a suggestion? I am quite lost.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** > my question is vague

My final intent is to rebuild the tables from the dump, incrementally, avoiding lookups outside the database. Every now and then I am gonna run a script that will select new tenants, users, posts and comments and add them to their corresponding tables.

My previous solution worked as follows:

1. Cache the whole database
2. For each new row, search for the columns inside the cache
3. If it doesn't exist, then insert it

I know it sounds dumb, but it made sense as a new developer working with ETLs

Comment: Does this query work? It has invalid syntax. Also it's quite unclear what do you want to do.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax, I am sorry!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It's a bit vague. Ideally what's your expected outcome?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I have added some extra information

Comment: Come to chat if you can https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160130/47559271

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I need 20 reputation to chat. I will try to find the password of my old account!

Comment: You now have 20.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what is your data, what is being provided to you and what the end goal is. I think that in your `mytable` the only identity column that is yours is the first `id` column and that the rest is from the data dumps provided by your supplier. From this monolithic table you are trying to break it down into separate tables on your end with unique rows. What is unclear is the schema of your target tables and the relationships between them. Are both P_Id and C_Id unique to the T_Id or are they unique to both T_Id and U_Id? Is this your goal or am I way off?

Comment: @EricJ.Price There are multiple databases, that are called Tenants in my example, identified by T_Id. Inside each tenant database, there are Users. A user may have multiple posts. Each post may have multiple comments. To find a unique constraint inside the dump, you must join the T_Id with other Id of your choice. My intention is to break the dump into separate tables: Tenant, User, Post and Comment.

Comment: Would each table have an identity column that you add so that you can uniquely associate each level down with the level above? So T_Id could be the top level unique in `Tenant` and then `User` would have User_ID, T_ID, U_ID so that `Post` could have Post_ID, User_ID, P_ID where User_ID would consolidate T_ID and U_ID and then `Comment` would be Comment_ID, Post_ID and C_ID? -OR- do you want compact tables with junction tables so if you have two tenants with a user name John then `tenant` would have two rows `user` have one and `tenant_user` would have two rows with diff t_id and same u_id?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a full flat DB dump, I'll suggest you to work on your file before even importing it in your DB (low level file processing is pretty cheap and nearly instantaneous).

From [Removing lines in one file that are present in another file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781434/removing-lines-in-one-file-that-are-present-in-another-file-using-python) you can remove all the already parsed line since your last run.

```
with open('new.csv','r') as source:
    lines_src = source.readlines()
with open('old.csv','r') as f:
    lines_f = f.readlines()
destination = open('diff_add.csv',"w")
for data in lines_src:
    if data not in lines_f:
        destination.write(data)
destination.close()
```

This take less than five second to work on a 900Mo => 1.2Go dump. With this you'll only work with line that really make change in one of your new table.

---

Now you can import this flat DB to a working table.

As you'll have to search the needle in each line, some index on the `id`s may by a good idea (go to composite index that use your Tenant_id first).

For the last part, I don't know exactly how your data look, can you have some update to do ?

The [Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) can help you too with this kind of problem.